# Animate jQuery state does not hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate a div holding an image to fold up and reveal a div that is underneath it. I have the div on top with a higher z-index decrease its height to reveal what is underneath with a lower z-index with a jQuery animate function with hover. However, the animation does not hold, and reverts immediately after it is finished. Can anyone help find the solution to make it stay in the animated state while the cursor is still hovered on the box?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.artist').hover(function() {
        $('.container',this).animate({'height':'9.1vw'}, 'fast');
    });


});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCPJc/1/)

Comment: okay this does not help

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated code. You're animating .container, instead of the .artistimage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.artist').on("mouseenter", function() {
        $('.artistimage',this).animate({'height':'9.1vw'}, 'fast');
    }).on("mouseleave",function(){
            $('.artistimage',this).animate({'height':'11.5vw'}, 'fast');
    });
});
```

here's the jsfiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/LCPJc/3/

Comment: Beauty. It had not occurred to me that animating that would make a difference. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Also, would you know a way for the image to stay put and just trim off the bottom? Right now changing the height causes the whole thing to move up.

Comment: if you set it up like the jsfiddle for your html (.artistimage inside the .container div) and set the height of the .container div to 11.5vw, it should work. The jsfiddle setup seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the image inside the `.container`. It just resizes after the animation is done.

You can solve this in multiple ways. You can set `overflow:hidden;` on the container, you can choose to resize the image instead or both at the same time. It depends of the end result you want. Resizing the image can change the aspect ratio of it and ruin the photo, for example, so you can go with the `overflow: hidden;` option if you want to avoid that.

Besides that, I advice to change the animation to css, like this:

```
.container{
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: height 0.15s;
}

div.artist:hover .container{
   height: 9.1vw;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c2rC/).